# How to get multiple identical maximum values

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to build a query which gives me some users having max of sum of amount. I can get the max by `limit 1`. But as there can be possibility of having the same value of max for multiple users how can I achieve this?

For example I have table as `ID, CONTACT_ID, ..., AMOUNT, ....`

Currently I am using this kind of query:

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS total,CONTACT_ID 
    FROM TABLE 
    WHERE ID = 1  
    GROUP BY CONTACT_ID     
    ORDER BY total DESC limit 1
```

If I try to use MAX() function. It gives me all the rows instead of max.

```
SELECT total,CONTACT_ID FROM
(SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS total,CONTACT_ID 
    FROM TABLE 
    WHERE ID = 1  
    GROUP BY CONTACT_ID     
    ORDER BY total DESC)
GROUP BY CONTACT_ID
HAVING total = MAX(total)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HAVING applies after the aggregation has been done. So the `MAX(total)` row in each group has already been chosen, which implies that the only `total` value left *is* the largest value.

You need to do this in two steps: first determine the largest total, then get all rows with that value:

```
SELECT total, CONTACT_ID
FROM (SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS total, CONTACT_ID 
      FROM MyTable 
      WHERE ID = 1  
      GROUP BY CONTACT_ID)
WHERE total = (SELECT SUM(AMOUNT)
               FROM MyTable 
               WHERE ID = 1  
               GROUP BY CONTACT_ID
               ORDER BY 1 DESC
               LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: Actually That `ID=1` also comes from a large sub query. So is there any way to avoid it in 2 steps?

Comment: Only with a [common table expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html), which is not supported in all Android versions, or a view.

Comment: So I need to duplicate the whole part is the only solution?

Comment: I mentioned two other solutions. You have to decide yourself if they work in your case.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score -1):

At first sight, i'd use a secondary request such as :

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS total,CONTACT_ID 
    FROM TABLE 
    WHERE ID = 1
    AND total=(SELECT MAX(SUM(AMOUNT)) FROM TABLE GROUP BY CONTACT_ID)
    GROUP BY CONTACT_ID     
    ORDER BY total DESC
```

Nota : The WHERE ID = 1; comes from your first request

Comment: thanks for correction, i missed the right AS syntax.